# Dictionary one key many values in code c#

Tags: c#, dictionary

There is

```
Dictionary<string,List<string>> dictionary=new Dictionary<string,List<string>>();
```

and

```
var c;

var c returns me values : 
100, "somestring"
100,"someotherstring"
200,"two"

foreach(var d in c)
{
 dict.Add(d.key,d.value);
// Need to add key value pairs here for dictionary. if key is same then values should get concatenated.
}

foreach(keyvaluepair<string,List<string>> pair in dictionary)
{
    // This loop should output something like below...
       100,"somestring,someotherstring"
       200,"two"

}
```

Comment: I agree with @Duane.. go back to your old questions and accept the answers that helped you.. then we'll be happy to help further..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a dictionary with `List<string>` as value, and then just add values :

```
foreach(var d in c)
{
  if (!dict.ContainsKey(d.Key))
    dict.Add(d.Key, new List<string>());
  dict[d.Key].Add(d.Value);
}
```

and later you can get comma delimited string from list with `string.Join`

```
string commaDelimitedList = string.Join(",", valueList.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have duplciate keys in a dictionary so the line of code `dict.Add(d.key,d.value);` will throw exception

Answer (score 1):

impossible, create own class with fields `key` `value` for this purpose

Comment: ya.. so how should i accompalish this in above foreach loop ..this is what i'm looking out for..

Answer (score 0):

When you add the values you have to check if the key exists:

```
if (!dict.ContainsKey(d.key)) {
  dict.Add(d.key, new List<string>());
}
dict[d.Key].Add(d.Value);
```

When you output the values, join the strings:

```
Console.Write(pair.Key + ", " + String.Join(", ", pair.Value));
```

Comment: thanks .. working fine replacing pair.Value with pair.toArray()

Comment: @user1502952: Yes, you need that for older framework versions.